# How to monitor Pub/Sub publish message size absent with StackDriver?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-stackdriver

See screenshot below.
I am trying to set up an alert that triggers when the "publish message size" metric is absent to detect if no data is being published on the GCP Pub/Sub topic.
The way I set it up (see screenshot) does not trigger the alert. When moving my mouse on the gap of data, a value for the metric is still available.

How do I set this up correctly?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Could you add `project_id` to "Group By", save the changes and monitor if this helps your alert to trigger?

Also I believe what you see as a "ghost" datapoint is just the last value depending if you move your mouse from left to right ot right to left.

Comment: I've added it. It does not happen too often, but I will try to see if I can trigger it in preprod.

Comment: Hi! just following up on this. I'm wondering adding  project_id to "Group By" helped you. Regards :)